# Matlab: generate random numbers from normal distribution with given probability

Tags: matlab, random

As seen in the code below, I am currently generating `random` numbers from a `Normal Distribution` and am selecting the ones within the `-3*sigma` and `3*sigma` interval. However, I now want to generate numbers such that there is a higher probability that I select numbers from outside the `-3*sigma` and `3*sigma` interval. For eg. A number from `[-4*sigma -3*sigma)` should have `35%` probability of being chosen and same for `[3*sigma 4*sigma)`. **Basically, I'll be calling this function several times and am wondering if there is a way for me to select a higher proportion of random numbers from the "tails" of the normal distribution, without actually altering the shape of the normal distribution.** I'm struggling to do this.

```
function [new_E11, new_E22] = elasticmodulusrng()

new_E11 = normrnd(136e9,9.067e9,[1 1]);

new_E22 = normrnd(8.9e9,2.373e9,[1 1]);

while new_E11<=-3*9.067e9 && new_E11>=3*9.067e9
        new_E11 = normrnd(136e9,9.067e9,[1 1]);
end

while new_E11<=-3*2.373e9 && new_E11>=3*2.373e9
        new_E22 = normrnd(8.9e9,2.373e9,[1 1]);
end
```

Thanks

Comment: But in that case it won't be a normal distribution anymore. How do you want to alter its shape?

Comment: I essentially want to generate the Normal distribution for `new_E11`, for example, using the mean 136e9 and S.D. 9.067e9 and then I want to select points from the intervals [-4*sigma -3*sigma) and [3*sigma 4*sigma) with a probability of 35% each. Is this possible?

Comment: The probability of those points is determined by the shape of the distribution, and is much smaller than that.

Comment: @Jojo it is not possible to do that using a *normal* distribution. You must choose a different kind of distribution to achieve this. Perhaps by adjusting skewness or kurtosis, but more likely by choosing a totally different sort of distribution.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the comment. I was just wondering is there a way for me to manipulate the random number generator such that I only select random numbers from within the aforementioned intervals?

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for the comment. Is there a way by which I can manipulate the random number generator to only select random numbers from within the aforementioned intervals?

Comment: try [Rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) or [Metropolis–Hastings algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm)

Comment: @bdecaf I've been looking into the Rejection sampling method, but am unsure what function I could use to represent the "tails" of the Normal distribution. And with regards, to the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, since the samples are dependant _I guess I could use this condition to increase the probability of samples from the Normal Distribution tails being chosen?_
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question does not make much sense, as pointed out by Jojo: this is not a normal distribution anymore.

What you could do is to create your own Probability density functions [pdf](http://www.mathworks.se/help/stats/pdf.html) and draw from it.

For instance,

```
N = pdf('Normal',-5:0.2:5,0,1);
```

gives you the normal PDF with a good resolution.
You could alter it, say

```
Z = N;
Z(5:15)=3*Z(5:15);
Z(35:45)=3*Z(35:45);
```

and use Direct Methods, Inversion Methods, or Acceptance-Rejection Methods as explained [here](http://www.mathworks.se/help/stats/common-generation-methods.html)

There is an implementation in the FileExchange:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27590-simple-rejection-sampling

Comment: I see what you mean. I've been looking into using the Acceptance-Rejection Method upon getting the "target distribution" which is N. However, I don't see how I could possibly model the "proposed distribution" which are the tails of the Normal Distribution? Thanks